# How to make JSON object of JSON objects

Tags: java, android, json

I have been working with a few JSON objects and have been keeping the outer JSON an array, but is it possible to keep the outer a JSON object and have it contain other JSON objects or arrays?

This is what I have and it is in proper form and works well:

```
{
"outer":[{
  "profile":{
     "image":"",
     "name":"",
     "password":"",
     "favorites":[

     ]
  },
  "friends":[
     {
        "name":"",
        "image":"",
        "number":"",
        "type":"",
        "birthday":"",
        "state":""
     }
  ]
}]
}
```

However, is it possible to have this:

```
{
"outer":{
  "profile":{
     "image":"",
     "name":"",
     "password":"",
     "favorites":[

     ]
  },
  "friends":[
     {
        "name":"",
        "image":"",
        "number":"",
        "type":"",
        "birthday":"",
        "state":""
     }
  ]
}
}
```

This is also in proper form, but I am having trouble adding multiple JSON objects and JSON arrays to a single JSON object in Android.  Every time I have the outer JSON object, it overwrites whichever object is already in there when I add another one.

This is what I've got so far.  obj1 is the profile JSON object and obj2 is the friends JSON object:

```
JSONObject profile = new JSONObject();
profile.put("profile", obj1);
JSONObject friends = new JSONObject();
friends.put("friends", obj2);
JSONObject outer = new JSONObject():
outer.put("outer", profile);
outer.put("outer", friends);
```

Comment: How are you adding those objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference of the second JSON is that you created a `List<outer>` instead of just an `outer` object.

```
JSONObject profile = new JSONObject();
profile.put("image", anImage); //pseudo code
profile.put("name", aProfileName); //pseudo code
//...and so on

JSONObject friends = new JSONObject();
friends.put("name", aName);
//...and so on

JSONObject outer = new JSONObject();
outer.put("profile", profile);
outer.put("friends", friends);

JSONObject outers = new JSONObject();
outers.put("outer", outer);
```

Comment: Actually, he created an object `outer` with another object `outer` inside (which is overriden in the second `outer.put("outer")`). I don't think `JSONArray` even have a `put` method (he would have to use `add` instead)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your mistake:

```
JSONObject profile = new JSONObject();
profile.put("profile", obj1);
JSONObject friends = new JSONObject();
friends.put("friends", obj2);
JSONObject outer = new JSONObject():
outer.put("outer", profile); 
outer.put("outer", friends); // you are overriding the profile value you have just put
```

To achieve this example by using `JSONObject`s:

```
{
    "outer":
     {
        "profile":
         {
            "image":"",
             "name":"",
             "password":"",
             "favorites": [] 
         },
        "friends":
         {
             "name":"",
             "image":"",
             "number":"",
             "type":"",
             "birthday":"",
             "state":""
         } 
    }
}
```

You should do something like this:

```
JSONObject profile = new JSONObject();
profile.put("image", "");
profile.put("name", "");
profile.put("password", "");
profile.put("favorites", new JSONArray());

JSONObject friends = new JSONObject();
friends.put("name", "");
friends.put("image", "");
friends.put("number", "");
friends.put("type", "");
friends.put("byrthday", "");
friends.put("state", "");

JSONObject outer = new JSONObject():
outer.put("profile", profile);
outer.put("friends", friends);
```

---

I strongly recommend you to **parse your String JSON into an JAVA object** for better **readability** and **cheaper maintenance** in the future

For that, I recommend you to use an external library like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and use it like this:

```
String json; // your JSON object as a string
Gson gson = new Gson(); // initializing the library object 
YourJavaObject yourJavaObject = gson.fromJson(json, YourJavaObject.class) // parsing

public class YourJavaObject 
{
    Profile profile;
    Friends friends;
}

public class Profile
{
    String image;
    String name;
    String password;
    List<Object> favorites;
}

public class Friends
{
    String name;
    String image;
    String number;
    String type;
    String birthday;
    String state;
}
```

Comment: I know that works, that's what I was saying.  I'm just not sure how to implement it in code.  If I have obj1 and obj2 that are both JSON objects, I can then make an outer one.  I say 'outer.put("profile", obj1) and outer.put("friends", obj2)', but then when I look at it, all that is there is the "friends" object, since it overrode the profile one.  How do I get around this?

Comment: Oh, now i got it. Could you show us how you are trying to do it?
I would recommend you to parse your JSON object to an JAVA object and then do your thing

Comment: You are putting your JSON objects in the same variable "outer", thats why it's overriden

Comment: How would I be able to write this to internal memory?  I'm using JSON form so that I can easily write it to memory and store it.

Comment: You mean persisting the JAVA Object into your app database in the phone or Shared Preferences?

Comment: If you do mean that, i recommend you to create another question and send me the link to it. It's a whole new question and my answer here would get too big. I have a good pattern to handle Android DB persistency that i can share with you

Comment: [Here is my question I posted for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229240/more-efficient-ways-to-store-information-in-android-database)