# More efficient ways to store information in Android Database

Tags: android, json

For a while now, I've been using JSON formatting to store information in Android applications.

However, this is sometimes messy and I feel like it is inefficient in some aspects.  I just have a more general question: **are there any more efficient ways to store information in Android applications?**

Comment: have you considered using Shared Preferences?

Comment: depends on what you store and how big data you store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [store information in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) in 4 ways:

1. Persisting in a custom **Database**

   - Relational data
   - Multiple instances of the same structure
   - Don't lose data after the app process is killed
   - Heavier operations
2. Persisting in Android's **Shared Preferences**

   - Simple data like primitive types (`boolean`, `string`, `int`..) that only occurs once
   - Don't lose data after the app process is killed
   - Light operations
3. Persisting in a **file** in the internal/external memory

   - Depending on your choice, can be like **1.** or **2.**
   - Harder to maintain than **1.** or **2.**
4. Holding it in **memory**

   - Data  lost when your app process is killed
   - Lightest of all options

Which one are you interested in?

I would recommend **1.** or **2.** for most cases, but i still need more info

---

**SQLite Database** (using a DAO pattern that i recommend)

*DatabaseHelper.class*

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "your_app_name.db";
   private static final String TABLE_MODEL_CREATE=
                               "create table " + Model.TABLE_NAME
                               + " ( "
                               + Model.COLUMN_ID+ " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                               + Model.COLUMN_SOME_INTEGER + " integer, "
                               + Model.COLUMN_SOME_STRING  + " text "
                               + " );"; 

   public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
   {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   // will run if there is no DB with your DATABASE_NAME
   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
   {
      database.execSQL(TABLE_MODEL_CREATE); 
   }

   // will run if there is already a DB with your DATABASE_NAME and a lower DATABASE_VERSION than this
   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
   {
      // execute all the updates you want
      database.execSQL(UPGRADE_1); 
      database.execSQL(UPGRADE_2);
      // ...
      onCreate(database);
   }
}
```

*ModelDAO.class*

```
public class ModelDAO {

   private SQLiteDatabase database;
   private DatabaseHelper dbHelper; 

   public ModelDAO(Context context)
   {
      dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
      database = GarcomApplication.db;
   }

   public void open() throws SQLException
   {
      database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   }

   public void close()
   {
      dbHelper.close();
   }

   public Model createModel(Model model)
   { 
      ContentValues values = modelToContentValues(model);

      long insertId = database.insert(Model.TABLE_NAME, null, values); 
      return getModel(insertId);
   }

   public Model updateModel(Model model)
   {
      ContentValues values = modelToContentValues(model);

      int rowsAffected = database.update(Model.TABLE_NAME, values, Model.COLUMN_ID + " = " + model.getId(), null);
      if (rowsAffected > 0)
      {  
         return getModel(model.getId());
      }

      return null;
   }

   public void deleteModel(Model model)
   { 
      database.delete(Model.TABLE_NAME, Model.COLUMN_ID + " = " + model.getId(), null);
   }

   public Model getModel(long modelId)
   {
      Cursor cursor = database.query(Model.TABLE_NAME, Model.allColumns, Model.COLUMN_ID + " = " + modelId, null, null, null, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      Model novoModel = cursorToModel(cursor);
      cursor.close();
      return novoModel;
   }

   public List<Model> getModelList()
   {
      List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<Model>();
      Cursor cursor = database.query(Model.TABLE_NAME, Model.allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

      cursor.moveToFirst();
      while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
      {
         Model model = cursorToModel(cursor);
         modelList.add(model);
         cursor.moveToNext();
      }
      cursor.close();
      return modelList;
   }

   private ContentValues modelToContentValues(Model model)
   {
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(Model.COLUMN_SOME_INTEGER, model.getSomeInteger());
      values.put(Model.COLUMN_SOME_STRING, model.getSomeString());

      return values;
   }

   private Model cursorToModel(Cursor cursor)
   {
      Model model = new Model(cursor.getLong(0), cursor.getInt(1), cursor.getString(2));
      return model;
   }
}
```

*Model.class*

```
// when you have time, read about implementing Serializable or Parcelable in your models
// it will help you to transfer this whole object throughout activities etc
public class Model { 

   public static final String TABLE_NAME = "model"; 

   public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
   public static final String COLUMN_SOME_INTEGER = "some_integer";
   public static final String COLUMN_SOME_STRING = "some_string";
   private final String[] allColumns =
   {
      Model.COLUMN_ID,
      Model.COLUMN_SOME_INTEGER,
      Model.COLUMN_SOME_STRING
   };

   private long id;
   private Integer someInteger;
   private String someString;

   // constructors, getters and setters

}
```

*Usage:*

```
ModelDAO modelDAO = new ModelDAO(someContext);
modelDAO.open(); // opening DB connection

Model newModel = new Model();
Model persistedModel = modelDAO.createModel(newModel); // inserting a new model
Model updatedModel= modelDAO.updateModel(persistedModel); // updating a model
modelDAO.deleteModel(updatedModel); // deleting a model

modelDAO.close(); // closing DB connection (NEVER FORGET ABOUT THIS!)
```

**[Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)**

```
// getting access to SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

// reading data
Integer yourInteger = prefs.getInteger("your_integer_name", defaultIntegerValue);  

// persisting data
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInteger("your_integer_name", yourInteger);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: 1 seems like what I'm heading towards.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok. This will take time. I will be saving my edits from time to time so that you can read it as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks man, this is really helpful.  I'll try some of this out.

Comment: I recommend you to use Shared Preferences where you can and use the sqlite database as a backup. If you need to store your data in a server database, thats a whole new thing